# C++ No Appropriate Default Constructor I am lost

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, abstract-class

I am stuck on a problem involving Polymorphism. My code keeps telling me that there is no default constructor for my class in this case I named creature, even though I did instantiate a constructor that takes a string in the creature class. I have a feeling I am missing something very small here and was hoping someone could help me with this. The code is as follows below.

```
class Creature 
{
public:

Creature(string);
virtual void DoAction() = 0;
virtual void DrawOnScreen() = 0;


protected:
string CreatureName;
};


Creature::Creature(string pname)
{
this->CreatureName = pname;
}; 


class Monster : public Creature
{

Monster(string CreatureName);
void DoAction();

protected: 
string CreatureName;

};


Monster::Monster(string pname)
{
this->CreatureName = pname;
};

class Player : public Creature
{
Player(string CreatureName);
void DoAction();

protected:
string CreatureName;
};

Player::Player(string pname)
{
this->CreatureName = pname;
}

class WildPig : public Creature
{
WildPig(string CreatureName);
void DoAction();
protected:
string CreatureName;
};

WildPig::WildPig(string pname)
{
this->CreatureName = pname;
}

class Dragon : public Creature
{
Dragon(string CreatureName);
void DoAction();
protected:
string CreatureName;
};

Dragon::Dragon(string pname)
{
this->CreatureName = pname;
}
```

I only included the classes within this snippet to keep it short and focused on where I believe the problem lies. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your subclass constructors should call the parent class constructor with the `string` parameter. `Monster(string pname) : Creature(pname) { }`

Comment: You say "even though", but you did not mention a contradiction. You defined a constructor taking a parameter. There is no constructor that takes no parameters (a.k.a. a default constructor).

Comment: Derived classes don't need to have `string CreatureName;` as it is already inherited from base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Monster::Monster(string pname)
{
    this->CreatureName = pname;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
Monster::Monster(string pname) : Creature()
{
    this->CreatureName = pname;
}
```

And `Creature` doesn't have default constructor. You need:

```
Monster::Monster(string pname) : Creature(pname) {}
```